# regex not able to allow tab

Tags: javascript, regex

i am trying to allow tab key in my regex function and its not working can anyone please help? find below my function:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
$('#myform').bind('keypress', function (event) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\/\ \b\t]+$");
    var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
    if (!regex.test(key)) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape all the backslashes(`\`) by using another backslash (`\`). So, the following code should work fine :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myform').bind('keypress', function(event) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[\\w\\-\\/ \\b\\t]+$", 'i');
    var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
    if (!regex.test(key)) {
      console.log(key);
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="myform" value="" />
```

Comment: i just used on chrome its working like a charm but on firefox no its still no work

Comment: yes sure but can you tell me why it wont work on firefox?

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution that works for both firefox and chrome:

```
       $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#myform').bind('keypress', function(event) {
      var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\_\\/\\s-\\b\\t]+$");
      var charCode = !event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode;
      if ([0, 8].indexOf(charCode) !== -1) return;
    var key = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
    if (!regex.test(key)) {
    console.log(key);
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

});
});